# Given a specific date return the specific occurence in the month

Tags: momentjs

I was wondering me if there is a way using moment.js to get the number of occurrence for a date.

For example:

Given the date **2018/06/01**, the app has to return: *First friday of the month.*

Given the date **2018/06/05**, the app has to return: *First tuesday of the month.*

Given the date **2018/06/12**, the app has to return: *Second tuesday of the month.*

Given the date **2018/06/27**, the app has to return: *Fourth friday of the month.*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a workaround for getting the value using moment.js, this function returns the number of occurrence in the month for a specific day:

```
function getWeekOcurrence(momentDate) {
    const month = momentDate.month();
    const clonedDate = momentDate.clone(); 

    for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        const substractedMonth = clonedDate.subtract(1, 'week').month();

        if (substractedMonth !== month) return i;
    }
}
```